# How to avoid casting to a JAXBElement while making a SOAP webservice call?

Tags: spring, jaxb, jax-ws, spring-ws, spring-oxm

I am having a spring boot java application. I am calling a soap web service using spring webservice template . the webservice call always return a JAXBElement. the following is my code snippet.

```
JAXBElement<ItemResponse> itemResponse = (JAXBElement<ItemResponse> ) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                this.cconfServiceConfiguration.getServices().getLocation(), itemRequest,
                new SoapActionCallback(this.cconfServiceConfiguration.getServices().getGetItemAction()));

        return itemResponse.getValue();
```

The marshalSendAndReceive returns a JAXBElement. Is there any way i can rewrite the code so that it will return an Object of ItemResponse so that i can avoid casting.
The following is the ItemResponse class declaration.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ItemResponse", propOrder = {
    "result",
    "item"
})
public class ItemResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Result result;
    protected Item item;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the result property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Result }
     *     
     */
    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the result property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Result }
     *     
     */
    public void setResult(Result value) {
        this.result = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the item property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Item }
     *     
     */
    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the item property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Item }
     *     
     */
    public void setItem(Item value) {
        this.item = value;
    }

}
```

really appreciate if you can throw some information